# Subset sum backtracking algorithm correctness proof

Tags: correctness-proof, backtracking

I'm trying to prove that the algorithm for subset sum, that is the algorithm that given a set of numbers $\\{x_1, \dots, x_n\\}$ and a number $K$ find if there is a subset $\\{x_{1_k}, \dots, x_{n_k}\\}$ that adds up to $K$.

Now one of the typical backtracking algorithm is of the form (I know there are better ways of writing this but this should be enough to try proving it, at least I think so).

```cpp
bool subset_sum(set, K) { // set with numbers and K an integer, assume the set is not empty
    if (K == 0) // we have found a subset that sums up to K
         return true;
    if (K < 0 or len(set) == 0) // We have summed more than K so we can skip exploring the tree
         return false;
     
    int value = set.pop();
    // we explore both branches of the backtracking tree 
    // adding the value and not adding the value
    bool backtrack_value = subset_sum(set, K - value) or 
                           subset_sum(set, K); 

    if (backtrack_value) // one of the branches found the sum
        return true;
    
    set.add(value); // we reset the set 
    return false;

}
```

Now I'm getting a real headache trying to prove correctness of this algorithm by induction (If it is even possible).

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems.

Comment: @Nathaniel I'm really lost setting up what even is my induction hypothesis, I tried using K, so base case $K = 0$ which is trivial but then I didn't know how to do the inductive hypothesis case when $n+1$. So that would be a good start.